# Iterative Control Flow in Subshelled Script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script(A) that is being called by another script(B).
In this script(A) I am creating some directories and moving some files as preparatory work for the rest of the script to work fine. Script(A) is called upon by script(B) in an iterative manner, I only want the creating of directories and moving of files to occur only once i.e during the very first loop.

What can I do to execute a part of my script only once?

Comment: Really? Upvoting a question with a useless title and no attempt at providing actual code...

Comment: @jasonwryan - good point about the title - guilty as charged. But the premise is very well and generally stated. I think the question is fine one, personally. We needn't agree, though.

Comment: @jasonwryan you are right about not having a decent title. Thanks for editing it who ever did it. I didn't had a code for this thing that's why I am posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some relatively unique quality of the environment upon which to rely. This is not easy to come by - especially if you are calling a separate script iteratively in a loop and expect it to behave differently for each occurrence *(why not portions of the same script in that case?)*.

Anyway, the common thing to do is to use a lockfile - or something like it - for these kinds of things. In order to do this though, you do need that unique bit of environment. Consider the following:

```
sh -c 'echo "$PPID" "$$"
       for i in 1 2 3 4 5
       do sh -c "echo \"\$PPID\""
       done'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
25711 28929
28929
28929
28929
28929
28929
```

If you can rely on the caller providing its pid to you in the environment variable `$PPID` it may be just what you need. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
#script a
LOCKDIR=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/${0##*/}.$PPID

init() { mkdir "$LOCKDIR" || exit
#        do other initialization tasks
}

loop() { : do the iterable tasks here; }

[ -d "$LOCKDIR" ] || init
loop
```

...and...

```
#!/bin/sh
#script b
a='/path/to/script/a'
for stuff in $things
do "$a" "$stuff"
done
rm -rf "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/${a##*/}.$$"
```

Seriously, though, I haven't encountered many situations at all in which doing this kind of thing is a good idea - if I am calling another shell-script iteratively and I must rely upon its environment then I would probably `.` source the script's contents into the current shell and run it that way. I would do this, that is, if I was *very* sure the script I was running was securely written.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is better to have a single script. However, the system that I am running is using scripts from different languages. This is how I have solved this problem.

touch Trigger.txt
n=$(wc -l <Trigger.txt)
if [ $n -eq 0 ]; then 
echo "The command is executed"
echo "This file has been used a trigger to set up working directories" >> Trigger.txt
fi

Comment: I have created a trigger text file, I am using the number of line count as the trigger for my if statement, then inside the if statement I am editing the text file to add more lines in it. That way the if statement will only be triggered once through whatever iterations.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to pass this information from the calling script to the called script. One is to use a parameter (`./script --init` vs. `./script`) or a parameter value (`./script --init=0` vs. `./script --init=1`). I guess the most simple method is to use an environment variable:

script B:

```
init=0
while whatever; do INIT=$((init++)) ./script_A; done
```

script A:

```
[...]
if [ 0 -eq "$INIT" ]; then
  : make preparations
fi
[...]
```

If script A shall be able to run without being called from script B then the missing variable must be handled (before the `if` statement, of course):

```
: ${INIT:=1}
```

Comment: this gens a syntax error as written in some shells. I will also do so if the caller does not set that env.

Comment: for script A the "if" statement line gives an error saying that an integer expression is expected. if I do it if [ $INIT -eq 0 ] then I will have to initiate INIT in script A which will be repeated every time.

Comment: @SyedMoez - exactly. Please look at the answer I posted here.

Comment: @SyedMoez Have you received this error when calling script A from script B or have you run script A directly?

Comment: @mikeserv Which shell fails with that? If no shell is given then I expect a solution to run in `bash`. I guess the original Bourne shell doesn't understand `$(())`. I am aware that the caller must set this variable but the question is about a caller callee combination, isn't it?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - the syntax error is not about `$(())` but `++`. If you did `$((init+=1))` you'd at least meet the POSIX spec, which is probably the assumption you should use as opposed to `bash`. And the `: ${INIT:=1}` is a bad idea - these kinds of things should have *some* amount of uniqueness to them, else they become security holes. Even pids (as suggested in my own answer) are something of a vector, but an incremented env var starting at zero that is not even initialized `${INIT:=0}` can be very *large* cause for concern.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a trigger text file, I am using the number of line count as the trigger for my if statement, then inside the if statement I am editing the text file to add more lines in it. That way the if statement will only be triggered once through whatever iterations. It is solved by a very simple code. 
touch Trigger.txt 
n=$(wc -l > Trigger.txt 
fi